# How to add a membership cards to my website that can member downloaded

Tags: wordpress

I have a website with Wordpress and I want to add members cards that they can fill their information and can download it from the website, but not sure how to do it I look for a plugin but I did not find.

also, I have 2 data on my website 'Event and Users' could I add them in one excel sheet or no?

I tried to look for a plugin

Answer (score 0):

you need to separate your questions and add more information about your problem.

I'll try to help you:

** members cards **

- You can use a form plugin to let the user fill the data (for example: name, surname, birth date, ecc..) that you need to print in the card. I suggest you to use this: https://formidableforms.com
- **the difficult way:** you can intercept the form submission with formidable specific function "https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/frm_after_create_entry/" and with the collected data you can create image in the fly with php and imagemagik (or GD or other) https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php. This part need that you have a little bit of experience in development. Check next point for a much simpler alternatives
- **the simple way:** With formidable you can create a post (or better custom post) with the collected data without working on code:
  https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/create-posts/ then you can redirect user to that page.
- Invite the user to print that page and setup a specific css for print: https://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries/